# VM error: revert. revert The transaction has been reverted to the initial state. Note: The called function should be payable if

Tags: solidity, contract-development, contract-design, struct, access

**Hi Guys**

I have two contacts first one is SubToken and second one is MainContract.

First I deploy MainContract after that I use createNewContract function and I create  new SubToken.

***and then***

I deploy SubToken with a address which is come from create contract function in my MainContract.

I want to access my name and I make a few functions in SubToken contract for that but I see revert error :(

**VM error: revert.
revert  The transaction has been reverted to the initial state.
Note: The called function should be payable if you send value and the value you send should be less than your current balance.  Debug the transaction to get more information.**

I dont know what am I supposed to do. Anyone can help me please :)

***Here's the a few ss of my code:***

https://eksiup.com/p/aj79538kzmgp

https://eksiup.com/p/w779539wzqmc

https://eksiup.com/p/9t79541aevh6

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.0; 
import 'https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/master/contracts/math/SafeMath.sol'; 

contract SubToken{ 
    MainContract mc;

    constructor(address _address) public{  
       mc=MainContract(_address);

    }  

    function getName1() view public returns(string memory){
        return mc.getNameMain(address(this));
    }



    //function transferFrom(address from, address to, uint tokens) public returns (bool success); 
    //function allowance(address tokenOwner, address spender) public view returns (uint remaining);  
    //function transfer(address to, uint tokens) public returns (bool success) ;  
    //function approve(address spender, uint tokens) public returns (bool success);  
    //function transferFrom(address from, address to, uint tokens) public returns (bool success);  

    event Transfer(address indexed from, address indexed to, uint tokens); 
    event Approval(address indexed tokenOwner, address indexed spender, uint tokens); 

} 
contract MainContract {
    //mapping(address => mapping(address=>uint)) balances;

    //mapping(address => mapping(address => uint)) allowed;

    address[] public contracts;

    using SafeMath for uint;

    address contract_address;

    struct token{ 
        string  name; 
        string   symbol; 
        uint8  decimals; 
        uint  totalSupply; 
        uint balances;
    } 
    mapping(address => token) public tokens;

    address mycontraddress;

    function createNewContract(string memory _name,string memory _symbol,uint8 _decimals,uint256 _totalSupply,uint _balance) public returns(address youraddress){ 
        SubToken st = new SubToken(address(this));//address(this)
        tokens[address(st)] = token(_name,_symbol,_decimals,_totalSupply,_balance);
        mycontraddress=address(st);
        return mycontraddress;
    } 
    function seeContracttAddress() public view returns(address){
        return mycontraddress;
    }

    function getNameMain(address _address) public view returns(string memory){
        return tokens[_address].name;
    }

    event Transfer(address indexed _from, address indexed _to, uint256 _value);
    event Approval(address indexed _owner, address indexed _spender, uint256 _value);

}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is not with your code. The problem is the order of issuing transactions.
You should follow the following steps:

1. Deploy **MainContract**
2. Issue **createNewContract** and get the returned address of the deployed **SubToken** Contract.

   ** Note that this address is the address of **SubToken** contract which has been deployed in **createNewContract** method. You need not deploy **SubToken** again.
3. Get instance of the **SubToken** Contract using the retrieved address in step 2.
4. Call the method **getName1**() of the instance of the **SubToken** Contract of step 3.

The problem was you were deploying **SubToken** Contract again and calling **getName1**(). Inside **getName1**() you called **mc.getNameMain(address(this));** The address you were passing as parameter had not been mapped in **token** of **MainContract**. So, as there was no entry with that address, it threw error.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using remix IDE make sure your ENVIRONMENT be Injected Web3 so simple!
[image: for cool guys who work with remix and injected web3 env]