# VM error: revert.The called function should be payable if you send value and the value you send should be less than your current balance

Tags: solidity, contract-development, contract-design, contract-debugging, access

There is already a [similar question](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/73969/vm-error-revert-revertthe-transaction-has-been-reverted-to-the-initial-state), but it doesn't help me. So I ask this question again and expect something useful information.

Two contracts named `AccessControl.sol` and `Judge.sol`. I've removed all the extraneous code, leaving only the wrong functions and get same error when call it.

First I deploy `Judge` contract and get its contract address. And then I deploy `AccessControl` contract, passed `Judge` contract address.

Finally I call `emitError` function in `AccessControl.sol` and see the revert error

> transact to AccessControl.emitError errored: VM error: revert.
>   revert  The transaction has been reverted to the initial state.
>   Note: The called function should be payable if you send value and the value you send should be less than your current balance.  Debug the transaction to get more information.

I have no idea about why it happened. Here is the simplified code。

**AccessControl.sol**

```
pragma solidity >=0.4.22 <0.6.0;

contract AccessControl{
    address   public owner;
    Judge     public jc;

    constructor(address _jc) public {
        owner = msg.sender;
        jc = Judge(_jc);
    }

    function emitError(address subject) public returns (uint penalty) {
        penalty = jc.misbehaviorJudge(subject, owner, "data", "read", "Too frequent access!", now);
    }

}


contract Judge {
    function misbehaviorJudge(address _subject, address _object, string memory _resource, string memory _action, string memory _misbehavior, uint _time) public returns (uint);
}
```

**Judge.sol**

```
 pragma solidity >=0.4.22 <0.6.0;

contract Judge {

    struct Misbehavior{
        address subject;   //subject who performed the misbehavior 
        address device;
        string resource;
        string action;   //action (e.g., "read","write","execute") of the misbehavior
        string misbehavior;
        uint time;   //block timestamp of the Misbehavior ocured
        uint penalty;   //penalty (number of minitues blocked)
    }

    mapping (address => Misbehavior[]) public MisbehaviorList;

    function misbeaviorJudge(
        address _subject, 
        address  _device, 
        string memory _resource,
        string memory _action,
        string memory _misbehavior,
        uint  _time) 
        public returns (uint  penalty) 
    {
        penalty = MisbehaviorList[_subject].length;
        MisbehaviorList[_subject].push(Misbehavior(_subject, _device, _resource, _action, _misbehavior, _time, penalty));
    }

    function getLatestMisbehavior(address _requester) public view 
        returns (address _subject, address _device, string memory _resource, string memory _action, string memory _misbehavior, uint _time)
    {
        uint latest = MisbehaviorList[_requester].length  - 1;
        _subject = MisbehaviorList[_requester][latest].subject;
        _device = MisbehaviorList[_requester][latest].device;
        _resource = MisbehaviorList[_requester][latest].resource;
        _action = MisbehaviorList[_requester][latest].action;
        _misbehavior = MisbehaviorList[_requester][latest].misbehavior;
        _time = MisbehaviorList[_requester][latest].time;
    }
}
```

Comment: "I've removed all the extraneous code" - you could also remove function `getLatestMisbehavior`.

Comment: @goodvibration I leave it for accessing the struct data if the code suddenly runs successfully. Then I will don't need edit, compile and deploy again.  And thanks a lot, It's stupid looks now but I actually find it the whole day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've declared function `misbehaviorJudge`.

But you've implemented function `misbeaviorJudge`.

So the way I see it, you are trying to invoke an unimplemented function.

---

A couple of ways for you to avoid a similar issue next time (more precisely, convert it from a hard-to-investigate runtime problem into an easy-to-investigate compilation problem):

**Option #1 - if you don't need to call function `misbehaviorJudge` inside contract `Judge`:**

File `IJudge.sol`:

```
interface IJudge {
    function misbehaviorJudge(...) external returns (uint);
```

File `Judge.sol`:

```
import "./IJudge.sol";

contract Judge is IJudge {
    ...
}
```

**Option #2 - if you do need to call function `misbehaviorJudge` inside contract `Judge`:**

File `IJudge.sol`:

```
contract IJudge {
    function misbehaviorJudge(...) public returns (uint);
```

File `Judge.sol`:

```
import "./IJudge.sol";

contract Judge is IJudge {
    ...
}
```

---

Then (for both options), in file `AccessControl.sol`, simply use `IJudge` instead of `Judge`:

```
import "./IJudge.sol";

contract AccessControl {
    IJudge public jc;
    ...
}
```